# exim4 show delivered messages

Tags: ubuntu, logging, email, exim

is there a command within exim4 (4.70-4.71) package (ubuntu) to display 
the message-id (exim's message-id) of delivered messages? (shows as Completed in /var/log/exim4/mainlog) ?

there is a `exim4 -bpu` command for undelivered ones.

Purpose: Tell and proof user that his mail was accepted by remote smtp and all problems are not our's :)
Size of log ~ 100 MB per day.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you actually *need* this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is **no builtin command** for this, but you could simply use `grep` and `awk`:

```
grep Completed /var/log/exim4/mainlog | awk '{print $3}'
```

Which should turn this:

```
2011-04-17 18:03:58 1QBUS6-0004Gc-1p Completed
2011-04-17 18:04:19 1QBUSQ-0004Lp-LT Completed
2011-04-17 18:05:16 1QBUTM-0004hP-Da Completed
2011-04-17 18:05:33 1QBUTd-0004jB-1M Completed
2011-04-17 18:08:23 1QBUWN-00052T-2E Completed
2011-04-17 18:09:39 1QBUXb-0005Co-Gc Completed
2011-04-17 18:09:51 1QBUXn-0005G0-6L Completed
2011-04-17 18:10:30 1QBUYQ-0005Jo-47 Completed
```

...into this:

```
1QBUS6-0004Gc-1p
1QBUSQ-0004Lp-LT
1QBUTM-0004hP-Da
1QBUTd-0004jB-1M
1QBUWN-00052T-2E
1QBUXb-0005Co-Gc
1QBUXn-0005G0-6L
1QBUYQ-0005Jo-47
```

Comment: Yeah, it is first that gets on mind. But this will parse this log , full log of some hundred MB eachtime. Ive been looking into perl script with File::Tail for this purpose.